# CSS Level 3 - validation (Parse Error [empty string])

Tags: css

I have the following code in CSS, which I am trying to validate with CSS Level 3, however I am getting the following error:

```
Parse Error [empty string]
```

on the line:

```
input[type="text"], select, textarea
```

The full code is

```
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 90%; /* Full width */
    padding: 7px; /* Some padding */ 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
    border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
    margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
    margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
    resize: vertical
```

Any suggestions? It is from a form I have made in HTML.

edit: Removing the border sections like people have suggested from other solutions does not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try googling "parse error [empty string]"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Validation: "Parse Error \[empty string\]"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837011/css-validation-parse-error-empty-string)

Comment: I have indeed Googled and checked the link you gave. There is a 'possible bug' which was from 6 years ago!! (which one would presumed has been fixed). Or has it? I can't just presume it was a bug, hence why I am asking people with more experience than me who may notice something else

Comment: If you click through to the bug report, you will see that it (1) is a real bug and (2) has not been fixed.

Comment: Ok, so the code looks fine? I ask as if every time a 'Parse Error' error came up, people just assumed it was a bug, it could cause problems. Thank you.

Comment: Also, if I remove all the border sections (which the link you gave said was the issue, it still does not validate.

Comment: Fixed it, it is not the bug. I forgot the closing '}' bracker. It compiles perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, it is not the bug. I forgot the closing '}' bracker. It compiles perfectly